# convert splunk api curl command to python

Tags: python, python-requests, splunk

I can run a splunk api call in bash and get back a SID which I then use to get back a splunk query. The first part of it is below. However, I am having issues when changing this to a python request using `requests`. I keep getting an `ssl CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` error.

Bash Command

```
data=$( curl -k -u username:password https://<splunk_endpoint>/services/search/jobs -d 'search=search earliest=-1m index=_internal')
echo $data
```

Bash Output:
      1538748227.228319_D07875A9-FDD6-46E8-BE77-EDF9BD9A73B1

python requests

```
import requests

baseurl = 'https://<splunk_endpoint>/services/search/jobs'

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

data = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    "search": "search earliest=-1m index=_internal",
}

r = requests.get(baseurl, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

I'm not exactly sure where to put the username and password. Does that belong in 'data'? in headers? somewhere else? I also don't know if my -d conversino to the data dictionary is correct. I think it is.

Any thoughts

Comment: Is the value of search three different parameters or is that all part of the search parameter for the api?

Comment: Also can you post the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Requests library verifies SSL certificates for HTTPS requests. You are most likely using a Splunk self-signed certificate which doesn't match.

You can ignore this check by adding verify=False to the get.

`r = requests.get(baseurl, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, verify=False)`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when looking for interacting with Splunk using Python's requests library. I could not figure out how to create the search payload. Here is my basic code for scheduling a job and obtaining the SID:

```
import requests
    
username = 'my_username'
password = 'my_password'
search = {'search':'search earliest=-5m index=_internal'}

r = requests.post('https://splunk-search:8089/services/search/jobs/', auth=(my_username, my_password), data=search, verify="/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem")

print(r.text)
```